# Setup MariaDB XA on WildFly through UI

Tags: wildfly, mariadb, xa

Similar to [How to setup MariaDB JNDI on Wildfly 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868226/how-to-setup-mariadb-jndi-on-wildfly-10) but specifically done through the Web UI.

I can create the non-XA data source with no issues but I am having issues creating the XA version.

I did the deployment of the mariadb-client.jar using the WildFly deploy UI with no issues.  I can verify that the non-XA datasource works well.

However, when I do the same approach with the XA driver, when testing the connection I get the following error on the logs (not visible on the error dialog

> Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031101: XADataSourceClass is undefined
>       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:621))

When I try to configure the driver configuration manually I just get Unknown Error and the datasource does not even get created

```
"failure-description" => {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.MariaDBXA"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.PacXA is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.MariaDBXA]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/PacXA is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.MariaDBXA]"
    ]
```

The driver classes I am using are as noted in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-2405 where I put it in the screen that accepts them.

- driver-class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
- xa-datasource-class: org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource (NOT org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource)

Also when looking at the XML when selecting from JAR vs entering the configuration on screen, nothing gets populated on `xa-datasource-class`.  I know I can edit the XML but like I said I wanted to do it through the administration console.

Comment: Please elaborate on why you need XA.

Comment: XA ensures that multiple resource types will work as a single transaction, e.g. JMS + JDBC that's the simplest example.  You can have J2C connections to the mainframe taking part of the transaction as well.

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-2405 for sample configuration. Make sure you are providing correct driver name.